# Auto update cart quantity when change quantity

Tags: cart, magento-1, shopping-cart, quantity

In the default cart of Magento, when the customer edit the quantity, he/she needs to press the button to update the quantity.

Is there a way that the cart update the quantity automatically when the user enter a other number in the quantity field?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First edit the cart template `/app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/checkout/cart.phtml` and add an id on the form element for easier access. Let's say you add 'id="cart-form"';

Now edit the templates that render the cart items:

- app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml
- app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/downloadable/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml

and on the `<input>` element with the name `cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]` add this:

```
onchange="$('cart-form').submit()"
```

But I don't recommend doing this. It's really annoying for the users. (at least for me).

Comment: Annoys the user?! No problem, we do it nevertheless :D

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt. Why not? We are annoyed when developing it, the user is annoyed when using it. That's what compromise means. Everyone loses. :)

Comment: You are awesome Marius. how can i do this using Ajax?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your site has jQuery included in no-conflict mode, here's a way of doing this asynchronously (much less annoying!).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#shopping-cart-table')
    .on(
        'change',
        'input[name$="[qty]"]',
        function(){
            var form = jQuery(jQuery(this).closest('form'));

            // we'll extract the action and method attributes out of the form

            // kick off an ajax request using the form's action and method,
            // with the form data as payload
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: form.attr('action'),
                method: form.attr('method'),
                data: form.serializeArray()
            });
        }
    );
});
```

I should point out that this makes the following assumptions:

- Your shopping cart lives within an element with the id of **shopping-cart-table**
- Your input fields for **quantity** have a name attribute that ends with **[qty]**

It should be easy to adjust the selectors in the code on lines 2 and 5 respectively to match your circumstances.

Comment: Hi Jetha I have tried this but it is showing the checkout/cart/updatePost/  302 Found 1.71s any idea why it is showing like this?

Comment: Parameters are this cart[137][qty] 
1
cart[139][qty] 
2
form_key 
zA1lLphVHPsEu4ux Using this how can i post this to update post action

Comment: Does your cart show the updated quantities?

Comment: It's not actually meant to return anything; more to the point you're not really meant to care about the return value when you do it this way.

Things to verify:
- does your form work when submitted normally, i.e. without AJAX?
- when the values are changed using AJAX, do the values in the cart (i.e. open another browser window) change?

Comment: Do you have anything custom that generates that notice?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33567/discussion-between-jetha-chan-and-naveen).

Answer (score 0):

Edit these two files

```
app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml

app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/downloadable/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml
```

and on the  element with the name `cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]` add this:

```
onchange="this.form.submit()"
```

Answer (score 0):

If your jQuery version is old, you will not succeed. I have found a way which is as follows, follow as our friend Marius's instructions to insert

`/app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/checkout/cart.phtml` and add an id on the form element for easier access. Let's say you add `id="cart-form"`

Now open file

```
app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/downloadable/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml
```

And scroll to the end of the file and you will find the javascript that does the increment and decrement of the quantity. The function will look like this:

```
function plusQty(itemId){
    qty = $('qty'+itemId).value;
    qty = parseInt(qty);        
    qty++;
    $('qty'+itemId).value = qty;
}

function minusQty(itemId){
    qty = $('qty'+itemId).value;
    qty = parseInt(qty);        
    if(qty>0){
        qty--;
        $('qty'+itemId).value = qty;
    }
}
```

Change for this:

```
function plusQty(itemId){
    qty = $('qty'+itemId).value;
    qty = parseInt(qty);        
    qty++;
    $('qty'+itemId).value = qty;
    document.getElementById("cart-form").submit();  
}

function minusQty(itemId){
    qty = $('qty'+itemId).value;
    qty = parseInt(qty);

    if(qty>0){
        qty--;
        $('qty'+itemId).value = qty;
         document.getElementById("cart-form").submit();   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't have jQuery loaded (yet), you can also find the `<input>`
 element (or in my case a `<select>` element since I built a dropdown field to select the amount) with the name `name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]"` and add this:

```
onchange="this.form.submit()"
```

The phtml file which you have to edit is located here:

```
app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml
```