# Update cart using Ajax Magento not working?

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">     jQuery(document).ready(function(){ jQuery('#shopping-cart-table')
    .on(
        'change',
        'input[name$="[qty]"]',
        function(){
            var form = jQuery(jQuery(this).closest('form'));    

            jQuery.ajax({
                url: form.attr('action'),
                method: form.attr('method'),
                data: form.serializeArray()
            });
        }
    ); });  </script>
```

I used this function for the Ajax update cart, ajax request is working but it is not updating in the cart, anybody done this ajax update cart please help me.

Comment: Can show the controller code where you have send ajax request

Comment: I haven't written any controller file for this, http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/55707/auto-update-cart-quantity-when-change-quantity/70361#70361

Answer (score 3):

Assume that  your *form action* url  is `checkout/cart/updatePost/` and  have no customization at `Mage_Checkout_CartController` at **updatePostAction()**.

Then you need to understand  that the request to `checkout/cart/updatePost` does ***not render the cart page*** content. So if you tried to get
 the cart page content from  the response, it's a waste of time. The response is a  302 redirect after the cart was updated.

So you need to use a customized cart controller.

Also make sure, that the **form_key** input field is present.

Comment: How to update quantity ajax through in mangeto1.9